# Pass MediaPlayer from Service to Activitiy with IPC

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ipc, inter-process-communicat

I am working on an android App which streams videos from internet. Therewith the app is also able to stream the videos in background, I hold the media player in a separate process' service. I had tried to run the service and activity in the same process, but on 20% of the smartphones the service will be destroyed if I press the homebutton. Therefore another process.
Now to my question. How to I implement this? In my main activity I need access to media player object of my service for setting the display to a surfaceview.

```
// This is the code I have used before, when Main Activity 
// and Service ran in the same process
@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder localBinder = (MediaPlayerService.LocalBinder)iBinder;
mVideoPlayerService = localBinder.getService();

mVideoPlayerService.mPlayer.setDisplay(readyHolder);
```

I read about using IPC - inter process communication. Can I solve this with IPC or if not, how is this possible?

Thanks, Mario

Comment: so why separate process? use foreground Service http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: yes I know, it isn't the right approach.
As you said, I used foreground service. It also worked, but only on 80% of smartphones. For example on LG G2 it didn't work. If I press homebutton the service still gets destroyed.
how can I solve this problem or on what could it depend on?

Comment: then the separate process is no solution either: it can be killed anytime, as far i know foreground services (with **startForeground()** being called) are the last victims to be killed in low memory detected

Comment: yes but on what could it depend, that startforeground only works on 80-90% of devices?
thats really strange...

Comment: doesn't it work at all? or only when your device is really busy?

Comment: no it doesn't work at all. Even if the LG G2 is not busy, the foreground service will be destroyed. I just read about bugs with Android 4.4. Perhabs it will depend on it.

Comment: so the built in media player (which uses foreground service) doesn't work on LG G2? hard to believe... btw do you call startService() or bindService() with auto create flag?

Comment: the built in media player works. i used bindService() with auto create flag.

Comment: call startService(), then bindService() you can pass 0 as flags and dont call startForeground() in your service, all should work then, to be more sure your service survives call startForeground()

Comment: thank you for now! I already modified my code, I will test it when I'm home from school! I will answer back, when I tested it.

Comment: so it seems to work, the service is running, even when I close the app, but I haven't tested the media player yet.
thank you very much for making me aware this bug! :)

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature